# ELOGIN error while connecting to the SQL server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, react-fullstack

I'm learning full stack web development and was trying to connect to SQL server from my backend Node.js. I was following an online video. While running the index.js file I get the below error -

```
ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'systemadmin'.
    at C:\Users\akunjalw\Desktop\FullStack\server\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:70:17
    at Connection.onConnect (C:\Users\akunjalw\Desktop\FullStack\server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1038:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:640:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at Connection.emit (C:\Users\akunjalw\Desktop\FullStack\server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1066:18)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\akunjalw\Desktop\FullStack\server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2574:20)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:639:28)
    at Parser.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at Readable.<anonymous> (C:\Users\akunjalw\Desktop\FullStack\server\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:32:12)    
    at Readable.emit (node:events:520:28) {
  code: 'ELOGIN',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'systemadmin'.
      at Login7TokenHandler.onErrorMessage (C:\Users\akunjalw\Desktop\FullStack\server\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\handler.js:239:19)
      at Readable.<anonymous> (C:\Users\akunjalw\Desktop\FullStack\server\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:26:33)  
      at Readable.emit (node:events:520:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
      at next (node:internal/streams/from:98:31)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
    code: 'ELOGIN',
    isTransient: undefined
  }
}
undefined
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

The code is as follows

```
const sql = require("mssql");

const config = {
  user: "systemadmin",
  password: "R@jasthaan1212",
  server: "localhost",
  database: "ORG_EMPLOYEEDATA",

  options: {
    trustedconnection: true,
    trustServerCertificate: true,
    enableArithAbort: true,
    instancename: "SQL2019",
  },
  port: 50685,
};

async function getEmployeeName() {
  try {
    let pool = await sql.connect(config);
    let employeeData = await pool
      .request()
      .query("select * from dbo.EMPLOYEES_DATA");
    return employeeData.recordsets;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

module.exports = { getEmployeeName: getEmployeeName };
```

```
const dboperations = require("./dboperations");

dboperations.getEmployeeName().then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Please let me know what exactly I'm missing here. I couldn't find the way to resolve this by searching in internet as well, may be I'm terrible at searching. Any help to resolve this is appreciated.

Comment: Can you connect to that SQL Server instance in SSMS?

Comment: Have you actually created an SQL Login account called `systemadmin`? Because the default administration account (when SQL Logins are enabled) is just `sa`.

Comment: yes, I created systemadmin login and am able to connect to the server instance through sql authentication @David Browne

Comment: Did you find out the reason for the same ?